# Development tool for M2Doc on Capella

Tags: m2doc

I'm looking for a debugger, or coding assistant that will allow us to quickly and efficiently use M2Docs to create our templates that will generate our documents.

Our current, workflow is, make a change, Save and close templates, run generation, open output, and scroll through doc to find if the change happened. See that it didn't, Scratch head, open the template Shotgun another idea, and repeat the process.

This is an inefficient method of programming, There has to be a faster way!

P.S. Sorry for not knowing the correct terminology, also looks as if the Mattermost chat server is down. is that correct?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the editing happening in MS Word we don't have content assist. We don't have a debugger neither, that could be added at some point.

We provide the [M2Doc interpreter view](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#m2doc-interpreter-view) (since 3.2.0), I takes .genconf file as context and allows to edit your AQL expressions using your variables or the current selection. It also provide content assist, validation, and a preview of the result. Once you have the result you want, you will need to copy the expression in your template.

If you are using an older version of M2Doc you can have a look at the [Sirius interpreter view](https://eclipse.dev/sirius/doc/specifier/general/Writing_Queries.html) and use the "aql:" prefix. You will not have specific M2Doc services in the completion.

Currently the [Capella forum for document generation](https://forum.mbse-capella.org/c/document-generation/21) is down. And the Eclipse foundation has moved from Mattermost to [Matrix](https://chat.eclipse.org) (I'm present on the Matrix server but not always reading the chat).